# Default imports are not resolving and referencing DLL files in DelegatedModuleFactoryPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, dll, plugins, module

I'm running into some weird behavior here when using the attempting to resolve default imports from a library included in my DLL build. For a bit of context here, I'm creating a DLL build using the webpack's DLLPlugin/DLLReferencePlugin that is comprised of a number of shared dependencies I want to use across multiple apps and not have to rebuild for each one. I have a pretty simple DLL setup in my `webpack.vendor.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'react',
            'react-dom',
            '@material-ui/core'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].dll.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dll'),
        library: '[name]_dll'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            name: '[name]_dll',
            context: __dirname,
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dll/[name].manifest.json')
        })
    ]
}
```

The above webpack config generates the following `vendor.manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "vendor_dll",
  "content": {
    "./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/index.js": {
      "id": "./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/index.js",
      "buildMeta": {
        "exportsType": "namespace"
      },
      "exports": ["Accordion","AccordionActions","AccordionDetails","AccordionSummary","AppBar","Avatar","Backdrop","Badge","BottomNavigation","BottomNavigationAction","Box","Breadcrumbs","Button","ButtonBase","ButtonGroup","Card","CardActionArea","CardActions","CardContent","CardHeader","CardMedia","Checkbox","Chip","CircularProgress","ClickAwayListener","Collapse","Container","CssBaseline","Dialog","DialogActions","DialogContent","DialogContentText","DialogTitle","Divider","Drawer","ExpansionPanel","ExpansionPanelActions","ExpansionPanelDetails","ExpansionPanelSummary","Fab","Fade","FilledInput","FormControl","FormControlLabel","FormGroup","FormHelperText","FormLabel","Grid","GridList","GridListTile","GridListTileBar","Grow","Hidden","Icon","IconButton","ImageList","ImageListItem","ImageListItemBar","Input","InputAdornment","InputBase","InputLabel","LinearProgress","Link","List","ListItem","ListItemAvatar","ListItemIcon","ListItemSecondaryAction","ListItemText","ListSubheader","Menu","MenuItem","MenuList","MobileStepper","Modal","ModalManager","MuiThemeProvider","NativeSelect","NoSsr","OutlinedInput","Paper","Popover","Popper","Portal","Radio","RadioGroup","RootRef","Select","ServerStyleSheets","Slide","Slider","Snackbar","SnackbarContent","Step","StepButton","StepConnector","StepContent","StepIcon","StepLabel","Stepper","StylesProvider","SvgIcon","SwipeableDrawer","Switch","Tab","TabScrollButton","Table","TableBody","TableCell","TableContainer","TableFooter","TableHead","TablePagination","TableRow","TableSortLabel","Tabs","TextField","TextareaAutosize","ThemeProvider","Toolbar","Tooltip","Typography","Unstable_TrapFocus","Zoom","alpha","capitalize","colors","createChainedFunction","createGenerateClassName","createMuiTheme","createStyles","createSvgIcon","createTheme","darken","debounce","decomposeColor","deprecatedPropType","duration","easing","emphasize","fade","getContrastRatio","getLuminance","hexToRgb","hslToRgb","isMuiElement","isWidthDown","isWidthUp","jssPreset","lighten","makeStyles","ownerDocument","ownerWindow","recomposeColor","requirePropFactory","responsiveFontSizes","rgbToHex","setRef","styleFunction","styled","unstable_createMuiStrictModeTheme","unstable_useId","unsupportedProp","useControlled","useEventCallback","useForkRef","useFormControl","useIsFocusVisible","useMediaQuery","useRadioGroup","useScrollTrigger","useTheme","withMobileDialog","withStyles","withTheme","withWidth"]
    },
    "./node_modules/react-dom/index.js": {
      "id": "./node_modules/react-dom/index.js",
      "buildMeta": {
        "exportsType": "dynamic",
        "defaultObject": "redirect"
      },
      "exports": [
        "__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED",
        "createPortal",
        "findDOMNode",
        "flushSync",
        "hydrate",
        "render",
        "unmountComponentAtNode",
        "unstable_batchedUpdates",
        "unstable_createPortal",
        "unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer",
        "version"
      ]
    },
    "./node_modules/react/index.js": {
      "id": "./node_modules/react/index.js",
      "buildMeta": {
        "exportsType": "dynamic",
        "defaultObject": "redirect"
      },
      "exports": ["Children","Component","Fragment","Profiler","PureComponent","StrictMode","Suspense","__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED","cloneElement","createContext","createElement","createFactory","createRef","forwardRef","isValidElement","lazy","memo","useCallback","useContext","useDebugValue","useEffect","useImperativeHandle","useLayoutEffect","useMemo","useReducer","useRef","useState","version"]
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, I have the DLLReferencePlugin in my main `webpack.config.js`:

```
new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
     context: __dirname,
     manifest: require(path.join(__dirname, 'dll/vendor.manifest.json'))
})
```

I do see the correct webpack "delegation" console logs when I do named ESM imports like `import {AppBar} from @material-ui/core`, but when I do a default import like `import AppBar from @material-ui/core`, I do not see the delegation logs where it notifies of successful referencing to the vendor dll.

I did some further investigation as to why the DLLReferencePlugin is not properly resolving the import from the DLL by throwing in some breakpoints in DelegatedModuleFactoryPlugin (used internally by DLLReferencePlugin) and saw this:
[Module Delegation within DelegatedModuleFactoryPlugin.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnKED.png)

The if statement that checks the if the path of the default export is present in the manifest returns false. The only key I have in the vendor manifest's content object for material-ui is `./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/index.js`:, so it makes sense why it resolves to false:
[Material-UI entry point key w/ exports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAuaU.png)

My current assumption right now is that when you add the name of a npm library as an entry point to the vendor entrypoint list, it only lists the main entry point as a key in the manifest, so anything that resolves outside of that path (i.e. a default import like `./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/AppBar/index.js`) is not getting referenced from the DLL. I guess overall my question here boils down to Is there something I'm missing here concept or configuration wise to get default imports to work?